# Working with (and saving) various image filetypes?

Tags: php, image, crop

I am working on a script to crop images. It's working on jpgs. But is there a way to make it apply to various file types (bmp, png, gif) **without** going through various if clauses?

```
//create the crop
// Original image
$filename = 'uploads/'.$image_name;

$endname = 'uploads/thumbnails/'.$image_name;

// Get dimensions of the original image
list($current_width, $current_height) = getimagesize($filename);

// The x and y coordinates on the original image where we
// will begin cropping the image
$left = 0;
$top = 0;

// This will be the final size of the image (e.g. how many pixels
// left and down we will be going)
$crop_width = 200;
$crop_height = 200;

// Resample the image
$canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($crop_width, $crop_height);
$current_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopy($canvas, $current_image, 0, 0, $left, $top, $crop_width, $crop_height);
imagejpeg($canvas, $endname, 100);
```

I tried replacing `imcreatefromjpeg` with `imagecreate` but that didn't work.

Comment: You might want to consider using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this purpose - it's way more flexible than GD2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`imagecreatefromstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) automatically detects filetype, but it requires image data as a string, but you could always do

```
$current_image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($filename));
```

Answer (score 0):

`scr` - for your source files
`dest` - for resulting files

```
     $size = getimagesize($src); 

        // Detect file format from MIME-information, detected by getimagesize() function
        // And select proper imagecreatefrom()-function.
$format = strtolower(substr($size['mime'], strpos($size['mime'], '/')+1));
$icfunc = "imagecreatefrom" . $format;
if (!function_exists($icfunc)){
    echo "Function $icfunc doesn't exists!");
}

    //Here is the magic: We call function, which name is value of variable
$isrc = $icfunc($src);

    // Create new img
$idest = imagecreatetruecolor($width_dest, $height_dest);

    // Copy src img to dest img with resizing
imagecopyresampled(
    $idest, $isrc,  // dest & src img ident
    0,0,      // dest img (x,y) top left corner
    0,0,      // src img (x,y) top left corner
    $width_dest, $height_dest,
    $width_src, $height_src
);
```